# How to change the image thumbnail dynamically by using Facebook web SDK

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook development newbie.

I have added the meta tags to the html file which I want to share to Facebook.
like:

```
<meta property="og:type"  content="article"/>
<meta property="og:title"   content="title"/>
<meta property="og:description"  content="description"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id"  content="23232323323232"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fajfladjfaljafl.jpg/>
```

I want to make the image thumbnail in Facebook profile different for different people. For example, people can do a small test here then share the result to Facebook, the image thumbnail should be the test result of that person. So how can I do this.

Now I am thinking to generate a new webpage within specific meta property for that person every time. But this's so dump!

Can I change `<meta property="og:image" content="https://fajfladjfaljafl.jpg/>` automatically when people share it to Facebook? or any other ideas?

Thank you very much!!

**Hi everyone:**

I am doing this via feed dialog. As what @Mosh Feu and @CBroe said, it doesn't make sense to change meta data.

I am using feed share link

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID&link=URL&picture=THUMBNAIL_URL&name=NAME&description=DESCRIPTION&caption=CAPTION&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
```

to define the parameters every time.

Comment: `dynamically when you share it to Facebook` How do you change it? Server? Client?

Comment: Actually I want to show different image thumbnail when different people share it. For example, people can do a small test here, and the image thumbnail should be the test result of that person. I am doing this on the server side.

Comment: From what I know, you can't change the the image thumbnail by change the `meta` tag, because Facebook store only one image per URL. So, you have to redirect the user to a unique URL page.

Comment: You need to use either individualized URLs, or do the sharing via the Feed dialog, that still allows to specify those parameters at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I am using Feed dialog now~